# How does DISTINCT interact with ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sqlite, language-lawyer

Consider the two tables below:

```
user:
ID | name
---+--------
1  | Alice
2  | Bob
3  | Charlie

event:
order | user
------+------------
1     | 1 (Alice)
2     | 2 (Bob)
3     | 3 (Charlie)
4     | 3 (Charlie)
5     | 2 (Bob)
6     | 1 (Alice)
```

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user FROM event ORDER BY "order" DESC;
```

will it be guaranteed that I get the results in the following order?

```
1 (Alice)
2 (Bob)
3 (Charlie)
```

If the three last rows of `event` are selected, I know this is the order I get, because it would be ordering 4, 5, 6 in descending order. But if the first three rows are selected, and then `DISTINCT` prevents the last tree to be loaded for consideration, I would get it in reversed order.

Is this behavior well defined in SQL? Which of the two will happen?  What about in SQLite?

Comment: you can't have a column in `order by` that is not in the `select` when using `distinct` keyword. I am not sure if your query will work.

Comment: Why don't you just order by `user` instead of `order`?

Comment: to quote from SQLite's [Order By](http://sqlite.com/lang_select.html) under *The Order By Clause* - "If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined."

Comment: @axblount Because the names here provided are just examples, and the order is incidental.

Comment: What is the goal of your query? As vkp stated you cannot have item in `order by` that isn't in `select distinct`.

Comment: The rows in `event` are inserted with a monotonically increased value for `order` column. I want to retrieve the latest order the `users` were inserted into `event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not be guaranteed.
Find Itzik Ben-Gan's Logical Query Processing Phases poster for MS SQL. It migrates over many sites, currently found at https://accessexperts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Logical-Query-Processing-Poster.pdf .
`DISTINCT` preceeds `ORDER BY .. TOP` and Sql Server is free to return any of `1     | 1 (Alice)` or `6     | 1 (Alice)` rows for Alice. So any of (1,2,3), (1,4,5) an so on are valid results of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: But if that fluxogram is correct, any cartesian join would take forever to compute if evaluated before WHERE clause.

Comment: Also, is that valid for SQLite? You said SQL Server would be free to return any. Does that implies that SQL standard leave the choice to the implementation? Does SQLite have stronger guarantees on this?

Comment: I have no standard at hand to give you direct reference, but ORDER BY is the very last operation by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query solution that I believe solves your problem.

```
SELECT 
    MAX([order]) AS MaxOrd
  , [user]
FROM Event
GROUP BY [User]
ORDER BY MaxOrd DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! I've asked specifically for the solution of my problem in another question. Can you please answer there so I can accept? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259972/how-to-get-the-order-distinct-rows-were-last-inserted-into-a-database