# How to get the order distinct rows were last inserted into a database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is a more to the point follow-up of my other question:

- [How does DISTINCT interact with ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257746/how-does-distinct-interact-with-order-by)

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    order TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    value INT NOT NULL
);
```

At every insertion, `value` will be taken from a finite set.

How do I get the order all the elements of my set were last inserted into the database? I thought of doing `SELECT DISTINCT value FROM event ORDER BY "order" DESC;`, but according to answer in my other question, this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from your other post.

Using max and grouping on the user you get the most recent timestamp by user.

```
SELECT 
    MAX([order]) AS MaxOrd
  , value
FROM Event
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY MaxOrd DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm assuming you mean where instead of were.

So if you're looking to order by insertion date descending, then it would be just as you have:

SELECT DISTINCT value FROM event ORDER BY "order" DESC;

I don't know why that wouldn't work. I tested it on one of my tables containing a timestamp and it works fine.